# Why is this recursive function that is supposed to make every element in a matrix 1 (used for maze generation) not working?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

```
function generator(x, y) {
    matrix[x][y] = 1;
    var arr = [1,2,3,4]; //randomizes the generator
    arr = shuffle(arr);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === 1 && matrix[x - 1] && matrix[x - 1][y] === 0) {
            generator(x - 1, y);
        }

        if (arr[i] === 2 && matrix[x + 1] && matrix[x + 1][y] === 0) {
            generator(x + 1, y);
        }

        if (arr[i] === 3 && matrix[x][y - 1] === 0) {
            generator(x, y - 1);
        }

        if (arr[i] === 4 && matrix[x][y + 1] === 0) {
            generator(x, y + 1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The results are bad. After execution most of the time on a 3x3 matrix gives back a 0 in the right or left corner up or even a row of zeroes.
As the matrix grows in size it is even worse.

Here is the result for a 15x15 matrix:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The matrix is initialized using this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    matrix[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

And the first call is generate(0,0);

Comment: Set a break point, step through your code, find out.

Comment: how do you initialise matrix ?

Comment: @yunandtidus edited

Comment: Doesn't look like the shuffle would have any effect on the output. Also there doesn't appear to be any upper constraint on Y. Its not the cause of your problem I think but how do you constrain it in the Y dimension?

Comment: @RichGoldMD I added everything now.

Comment: I tried out your code - it draws mazes but it looks like its terminating because the path hits a dead end

Comment: Like @RichGoldMD says: as soon as the generator hits a cell where it can no longer go up or down or left or right (because the path has already been there), it simply stops. This happens at random places.